# How to parse string/URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, url

I have ajax call and from json i get URL like this:

```
http://pp.somedomain.com/pp/url/245/http%253A%252F%252Fmydomain.com%252Fblog%252F25-03-11%252Fawesome-story-bro%252F%253Fstuff%253D492039402
```

Now I would like to parse that I would only get my domain.com path from that. So the end result would be:

```
http://mydomain.com/blog/25-03-11/awesome-story-bro/
```

But I have no clue how to do that with Javascript/jQuery. Anyone could help me out? I read tutorial and somehow I have to count / and then cut it somehow.

Comment: Use decodeURIComponent call -- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: @Kyo http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: ok then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: @Kyo Welcome the [devdocs](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/decodeuri) =)

Comment: Yes KYO is correct you should use encodeURIComponent and then decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html part has been encoded twice. You'd first need to use the html-unescape call and then later use the `decodeURIcomponent`.

Also, note that your URL in still incorrect since you've the following in it:

```
%252F%mydomain
```

Notice the **`%mydomain`** part? It should be:

```
%252F%252Fmydomain
```

and then you can use the following function calls:

```
x = "http%253A%252F%252Fmydomain.com%252Fblog%252F25-03-11%252Fawesome-story-bro%252F%253Fstuff%253D492039402"
y = unescape(x) // y = "http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fblog%2F25-03-11%2Fawesome-story-bro%2F%3Fstuff%3D492039402"
z = decodeURIComponent(y) // z = "http://mydomain.com/blog/25-03-11/awesome-story-bro/?stuff=492039402"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your url isnot valid.
When I try decode with decodeURIComponent(), it throws URI malformed exception

```
decodeURIComponent("http%253A%252F%mydomain.com%252Fblog%252F25-03-11%252Fawesome-story-bro%252F%253Fstuff%253D492039402")
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I pasted it wrongly. Maybe I missed some character? I'll need to check it.

Comment: Ok fixed the url in the first post. But still it looks like http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fblog%2F25-03-11%2Fawesome-story-bro%2F%3Fstuff%3D492039402  after decoding.

Answer (score 0):

To parse the url from the string-

Using **exec**

```
 var result = /[^/]*$/.exec(a)[0];
```

Using **lastIndexOf** and **substring**:

```
var n = a.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = a.substring(n + 1);
```

Then you can decode the url using `decodeURIComponent`-

```
var my_url = decodeURIComponent(result);
```

[View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VUBg9/)

(but it seems that the string is erroneous as explained by @hjpotter92. pl check)